# Android Studio on Yosemite

Tags: java, android, osx-yosemite

So I am trying to get android studio to compile my app for Android L as well as previous SDK's. Unfortunately when trying to compile I am getting a error stating that I do not have the nessecary Java JDK to compile for "L" which is JDK 7, so I did a bit of research and found a way to get JDK 7 to install on Yosemite(10.X). Still getting the error though. Just wondering if anyone else has had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the right SDK location in Android Studio as your default SDK or the project SDK.

Right click on the project and select "Open module settings". 
Select SDK location and check if the JDK path is the correct one.

Location for JDK7 changed a bit. This is my location:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Still getting this error

 DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.KevinSoares.learndeveloping"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.KevinSoares.learndeveloping
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Not sure if the JDK is sticking or not.

Comment: I think this could be it: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/ - To sum up. Use number 21 instead of the letter L in your configuration. And instead of android-L, android-21.

Comment: and the official thread: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72453&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars